# APA citation problem

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing, apa-style, cite-package

my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
{0pt}
{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{20pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75} 

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

It is particularly notable for its flexibility, its
superb hyphenation, and its ability to choose aesthetically satisfyingline\citep{Wel03}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

my bib file is:

```
@book{Wel03,
author = "Stefan Wellek", year = 2003,
title = "Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence",
publisher = "{Chapman \& Hall/CRC Press}",
address = "New York"
}
```

it compiles to:

[image]

I wanted to show the author and year. What is wrong with my code? I tried to read and search for answers but the information is just too overwhelming and sources differ from one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `natbib`.

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib}
  @book{Wel03,
   author = "Stefan Wellek", 
   year = 2003,
   title = "Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence",
   publisher = "{Chapman \& Hall/CRC Press}",
   address = "New York"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

It is particularly notable for its flexibility, its
superb hyphenation, and its ability to choose aesthetically satisfyingline~\citep{Wel03}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `biblatex-apa` the biblography has to be compiled with `biber` by default):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style = apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{apabibli.bib}
  @book{Wel03,
   author = "Stefan Wellek",
   year = 2003,
   title = "Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence",
   publisher = "{Chapman \& Hall/CRC Press}",
   address = "New York"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{apabibli.bib}

\begin{document}

It is particularly notable for its flexibility, its
superb hyphenation, and its ability to choose aesthetically satisfyingline~\parencite{Wel03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]